# In TypeScript, how to extend a base class located in another file when targeting IE11 (ES5)?

Tags: javascript, .net, typescript, .net-core, es6-modules

In TypeScript, I want to define a base class in one file that classes in a bunch of other files can inherit from. I see how this can be done using modules, but from what I understand IE11 does not support modules, so I need to set the tsconfig.json compilerOptions.module to "None", and therefore I can't use them.

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps using namespaces? Please give a complete example. A lot of the information is confusing online, because I know the terminology around modules and namespaces has changed with more recent versions of TypeScript.